# Docker: Build fail on another host with same configuration

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker in a developement environment. I have two pc, both with same OS (kubuntu 20.04) and same docker version.
In one the dockerfile build without errors, in the other fails with

```sh
$ docker build -t letsjump/mydockername -f docker-data/webserver73/Dockerfile .

#...lot of compile output...

configure: error: unrecognized options: --with-freetype, --with-jpeg, --with-freetype, --with-webp
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - &&     apt-key update &&     DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" install             $CUSTOM_BUILD_DEPS             $PHPIZE_DEPS             sendmail             git             mariadb-client             openssh-client             nano             netcat             linkchecker             nodejs             build-essential             libzip-dev             libz-dev             wget             unixodbc             odbcinst             unixodbc-dev             gnupg             libwebp-dev             libonig-dev         --no-install-recommends &&         npm -g install npm@latest &&         docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-freetype --with-webp &&         docker-php-ext-configure bcmath &&         docker-php-ext-configure calendar &&         docker-php-ext-configure pdo_odbc --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr &&         docker-php-ext-install gd                                intl                                pdo_mysql                                mysqli                                mbstring                                opcache                                zip                                bcmath                                calendar                                soap &&         pecl install memcached-3.1.5 &&         echo extension=memcached.so >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini &&         printf "\n" | pecl -d preferred_state=beta install xdebug' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

In both hosts I have the same OS (kubuntu 20.04 desktop) and almost the same Docker version.

In this host the dockerfile build succesfully:

```sh
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838
```

In this other not:

```sh
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
```

This is the dockerfile:

```dockerfile
# Dockerfile (c) letsjump 2018
FROM php:7.3-apache

MAINTAINER letsjump <letsjump@xxx>

WORKDIR /

COPY ./docker-data/webserver73/ /

RUN chown -R "$APACHE_RUN_USER:$APACHE_RUN_GROUP" "/usr/local/bin";
RUN chmod -R +xr "/usr/local/bin/";

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

RUN useradd -ms /dev/null dbmaker
RUN chown -R dbmaker:dbmaker /home/dbmaker

# define build dependency lists
# inherited from PHP base image:
# PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf  dpkg-dev file g++ gcc libc-dev libpcre3-dev make pkg-config re2c
ENV CUSTOM_BUILD_DEPS \
            unzip \
            libmemcached-dev \
            libicu-dev \
            libfreetype6-dev \
            libjpeg-dev \
            libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
            libxml2-dev \
            zlib1g-dev \
            libpng-dev
            
# list of other packages which could be deinstalled at the end
ENV CUSTOM_REMOVE_LIST cpp \
             cpp-4.9 \
             g++-4.9 \
             gcc-4.9 \
             libgcc-4.9-dev \
             libhashkit-dev \
             libsasl2-dev \
             libstdc++-4.9-dev 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -my gnupg

# Install system packages for PHP extensions recommended for Yii 2.0 Framework
# Install PHP extensions required for Yii 2.0 Framework
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - && \
    apt-key update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" install \
            $CUSTOM_BUILD_DEPS \
            $PHPIZE_DEPS \
            sendmail \
            git \
            mariadb-client \
            openssh-client \
            nano \
            netcat \
            linkchecker \
            nodejs \
            build-essential \
            libzip-dev \
            libz-dev \
            wget \
            unixodbc \
            odbcinst \
            unixodbc-dev \
            gnupg \
            libwebp-dev \
            libonig-dev \
        --no-install-recommends && \
        npm -g install npm@latest && \
        docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-freetype --with-webp && \
        docker-php-ext-configure bcmath && \
        docker-php-ext-configure calendar && \
        docker-php-ext-configure pdo_odbc --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr && \
        docker-php-ext-install gd \
                               intl \
                               pdo_mysql \
                               mysqli \
                               mbstring \
                               opcache \
                               zip \
                               bcmath \
                               calendar \
                               soap && \
                               # printf "\n" | pecl -d preferred_state=beta install xdebug
        pecl install memcached-3.1.5 && \
        echo extension=memcached.so >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini && \
        printf "\n" | pecl -d preferred_state=beta install xdebug
        # apt-get remove -y $PHPIZE_DEPS $CUSTOM_BUILD_DEPS $CUSTOM_REMOVE_LIST && \
        # dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ { print $2 }') && \
        # apt-get clean && \
        # rm -rf /usr/src/php* && \
        # rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
        
        #set -x \
        #    && cd /usr/src/php/ext/odbc \
        #    && phpize \
        #    && sed -ri 's@^ *test +"\$PHP_.*" *= *"no" *&& *PHP_.*=yes *$@#&@g' configure \

# odbc
# docker-php-ext-configure odbc --with-unixODBC=/usr --with-dbmaker=/home/dbmaker/5.2 && \
        # docker-php-ext-configure odbc --with-unixODBC=/usr --with-dbmaker=/home/dbmaker/5.2 --with-adabas=no && \

# Install less-compiler
RUN npm install -g \
        less \
        lesshint \
        uglify-js \
        uglifycss

ENV PHP_USER_ID=33 \
    PHP_ENABLE_XDEBUG=1 \
    VERSION_COMPOSER_ASSET_PLUGIN=^1.4.6 \
    VERSION_PRESTISSIMO_PLUGIN=^0.3.10 \
    PATH=/var/www/:/root/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH \
    TERM=linux \
    COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 \
    GITHUB_API_TOKEN=${GITHUB_API_TOKEN}

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
        --install-dir=/usr/local/bin \
        --filename=composer --version=1.10.16 && \
        composer global require --optimize-autoloader \
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:${VERSION_COMPOSER_ASSET_PLUGIN}" \
        "hirak/prestissimo:${VERSION_PRESTISSIMO_PLUGIN}" && \
        composer global dumpautoload --optimize && \
        composer clear-cache

RUN chown -R 1000:33 /var/www

# Install Yii framework bash autocompletion
RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yiisoft/yii2/master/contrib/completion/bash/yii \
        -o /etc/bash_completion.d/yii

# enabling specific apache2 modules
# enabling specific apache2 modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite && \
    service apache2 restart

WORKDIR /var/www
```

Yes, the dockerfile is probably a mess, with a lot of adds on the fly. But why it compiles in one host and in the other not?

**UPDATE**

After reading the reasonable answer of [aankhen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8492116/aankhen), I emptied the docker-data/webserver73 folder which in any case did not contain any relevant code except one apache virtualhost and one xdebug.ini configuration file in their relative folders.
The build failed again with the same error as above.
I also want to point out that the wevserver73 folder contains the exact same files as the one on the other host with the same owner and rights.

Comment: The `COPY ./docker-data/webserver73/ /` means that commands like `docker-php-ext-configure` could be running anything—it’s not possible to tell from the Dockerfile just what the problem is. Does that directory contain, somewhere in it, a `docker-php-ext-configure` that overwrites the one in the base image?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made some experiments and updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect failures to happen sporadically and periodically with this dockerfile. Why? Because you haven't pinned the versions of the majority of tools you're installing. You implicitly install the latest version of a bunch of GNU/Linux libraries and then explicitly install the latest version of npm and you follow this up by using npm to install the latest version of a bunch of javascript modules. I can see that you pin the versions of some libs, but to guarantee repeatability you have to pin everything.

Also, as @Aankhen said in the comments, you also have a copy command that is copying files from the local filesystem, which could contain anything and again is unlikely to result in a portable repeatable image.

The solution to this is a) pin everything, or b) use a registry to share an image that has been built once and rely on a pinned version of that. Generally, banks and large corporations require the pinning solution, and less regulated industries often go with the registry solution.

Comment: Thanks. This point me to a solution. If I build the dockerfile with --no-cache option, it crash on both hosts. The problem is with the [GD library configuration](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/865). I'll post an answer when I'll solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I answer to my question:

As [Software-engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2051454/software-engineer) said in his answer, pin, pin, pin.

In this case it was the PHP's mantainers (questionable) choice to change the Debian release [within a minor version](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/865#issuecomment-511217533) of the docker image (`php:7.3-apache`). Here they switched from *stretch* to *buster*.

So the new pulled php:7.3-apache image had a completely different OS and different dependent library and behaviors.

So, as Software-engineer said, the right and the fastest solution to this problem is to pin the PHP image to a tag related to the distribution: `php:7.3-apache-stretch`.

The slower and unstable solution, in case you want to use the unpinned version, is to adapt the GD `configure` options to the new release:

```dockerfile
...
docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-webp-dir --with-jpeg-dir \
            --with-png-dir --with-zlib-dir --with-freetype-dir && \
...
```

taking care to include the necessary libraries first: `libfreetype6-dev, libjpeg-dev` and `libjpeg62-turbo-dev`

But this will require a manual pull from the server for any host that has a non recent build of the same image.